# Vim <C-Right> and <C-Left> remaping

Tags: vim, shortcut

When i press `<C-Right>` in insert mode, vim does the same thing that it would being in normal mode and pressing w. But i would like to remap C-Right and C-Left so the effect would be more like the e key (specially at the end of a line, when i'm just before the last word i don't want vim to skip the line and go to the next line word, i want it to put the cursor just at the end of the line.)

I tried for the insert mode `:inoremap <C-Right> <Esc> e a` 
but it keeps jumping the line, besides `<Esc> e a` doing exactly what i want.

In normal mode, `:nnoremap <C-Right> E` does what i want.

What i am missing to make the remap work?

Thank you for your time reading the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put spaces inbetween the commands (or after them). All the spaces count as part of the command (which is move the cursor to the right)

```
:inoremap <C-Right> <Esc> e a
```

should be

```
:inoremap <C-Right> <Esc>ea
```